# QML Application Window moved to no non-viewable area and is no longer able to be moved to viewable area

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine, applicationwindow

I'm building a qml application, and the application window has the following hints set:  Qt.CustomizeWindowHint and Qt.Window. When trying to work on scaling the application on a click and drag that switches the state of the window from Maximized->Windowed, the application went out of view and is no longer reachable. I received the following error in the console:

```
QT_WARNING: QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1425x514-2147483648+241 (frame: 1439x528+2147483641+234) on ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_61_QML_65/"" on "\\.\DISPLAY4". Resulting geometry: 1425x514+32774+241 (frame: 1439x528+32767+234) margins: 7, 7, 7, 7)
```

Now even though I restart the program my application still returns to a state where I'm not able to view it. I'm using pyCharm as my IDE, windows 10 as my os, and this application is written in pyqt5/qml.

I'm able to see that application when I use Win+Tab but not when I use Win+L\R. I was hoping that I could figure out if this is common issue with customizable windows in qml, and if so what I need to do to allow a user to regain access the application window.

Also, if I remove the customizable window I'm able to regain access to the application by using Win+L\R.

Comment: Are you able to show some code? Preferably in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm not able to. I've resolved the issue for the time being but I think that it was a combination of customizing the sizing/placement of the window and storing the previous state of the windows position and size.